# Keeping shared keychain data private

Tags: ios, keychain, privacy

As Apple docs state, apps can share keychain data if they have the same *App ID prefix* and they've set the same *keychain-access-groups* in *Entitlements*.

However, I've been able to access shared keychain data from the app that has a different *App ID prefix* as long as I provide the proper *keychain-access-groups* as a hard-coded string. Like `ABCDEFGHIJ.my.keychain.group`.

It seems that keeping the *keychain-access-groups* value secret is the only thing that prevents someone from accessing the keychain data. Obviously, since it's just a plist value, this is not safe at all.

**Is there any way to ensure that an app that is not included in my Apple Developer Program will not be able to access shared keychain, even if it knows my *keychain-access-groups* value?**

Comment: Consider submitting this as a bug to Apple.